# HTML: Unexpected double row using rowspan

Tags: html, html-table

I want to create a normal table. But I need to put two fields in one row.
So, I used rowspan and expected to have a two row table, but with a space of fourth.
But, it's showed in only one line.
I revised, and look for something wrong, but I dont unerstaing.
When I remove the rowspan, everything looks normal, but I need the rowspan.
Why is render in one row?

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tbody>                             
    <tr  class="warning" >
    <td rowspan="2" >100</td>
    <td rowspan="2">87</td>
    <td rowspan="2">FERNANDO RODRIGUEZ</td>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <td rowspan="2">MARIANO ORTEGA SANCHEZ</td>

      <td rowspan="2" >  </td>
        <td rowspan="2" >  </td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <span class="label label-info">
                Importacion
                Sencillo
            </span>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2"> Monterrey </td>
        <td rowspan="2" ></td>
        <td rowspan="2" ></td>
        <td rowspan="2" ></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
         <a href="/TimsaLzc/web/app_dev.php/main/fleteDetalle/100" >
            <button class="btn btn-success">Detalles</button>
        </a> 
        </td>
</tr>

<tr  class="warning" >
    <td rowspan="2" >101</td>
    <td rowspan="2">82</td>
    <td rowspan="2">IVAN CORTES</td>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <td rowspan="2">MARIANO ORTEGA SANCHEZ</td>

    <td rowspan="2" >  </td>
        <td rowspan="2" >  </td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <span class="label label-info">
                Importacion
                Sencillo
            </span>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2"> Nissan Mexico </td>
        <td rowspan="2" ></td>
        <td rowspan="2" ></td>
        <td rowspan="2" ></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
         <a href="/TimsaLzc/web/app_dev.php/main/fleteDetalle/101" >
            <button class="btn btn-success">Detalles</button>
        </a> 
        </td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>   
</table>
```

This is a picture of my app in action, and the reason of my question.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1luaxgg4yesm8re/result.png

Comment: Well all your TDs have rowspan hence it is rendering in one row. There's no point in using rowspans if you use it each column.

Comment: Try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/5duCX/

Comment: I used a double row in some spaces. This is a picture of my app, and how this problem affect my solution.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1luaxgg4yesm8re/result.png

Comment: Everything is well, but when i used a double span in all the row.
It becomes creepy.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `rowspan`s with `colspan`s. For example:

```
<td colspan="2">
  (...)
</td>
```

**EDIT**:

Still not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve but as far as I believe you might want to:

- remove `rowspan` from all the `td`'s that are meant to be *two-rowed*.
- add and additional `<tr></tr>` after each `tr` and fill it with a number of `td`s equal to number of cells **with** rowspan.

Comment: You think? I just show a image that whta I want to do.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1luaxgg4yesm8re/result.png

Comment: Excluding CSS, table from the picture is the same as the one you provided in the code.

Comment: Yes. I just want to show you the double rowspan="1" in the firsts rows. That's why I think the colspan dont suit in what I want to do.

Comment: I just did it. The answer is to remove the rowspan=2 from all the td's that are meant to be one-rowed.
I didn't know that when you used rowspan=2, the next row try to fill the spaces where the rowspan=2 is put it. When it can't make it, the next row is put it in the same row, though you declare a new tr.
Thanks, you really help me.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem, try adding an empty Row at the end of the missbehaving Row something like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tbody>                             
    <tr  class="warning" >
    <td rowspan="2" >100</td>
    <td rowspan="2">87</td>
    <td rowspan="2">FERNANDO RODRIGUEZ</td>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <td rowspan="2">MARIANO ORTEGA SANCHEZ</td>

      <td rowspan="2" >  </td>
        <td rowspan="2" >  </td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <span class="label label-info">
                Importacion
                Sencillo
            </span>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2"> Monterrey </td>
        <td rowspan="2" ></td>
        <td rowspan="2" ></td>
        <td rowspan="2" ></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
         <a href="/TimsaLzc/web/app_dev.php/main/fleteDetalle/100" >
            <button class="btn btn-success">Detalles</button>
        </a> 
        </td>
</tr>
<tr /> <!--magic goes here-->
<tr  class="warning" >
    <td rowspan="2" >101</td>
    <td rowspan="2">82</td>
    <td rowspan="2">IVAN CORTES</td>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <td rowspan="2">MARIANO ORTEGA SANCHEZ</td>

    <td rowspan="2" >  </td>
        <td rowspan="2" >  </td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <span class="label label-info">
                Importacion
                Sencillo
            </span>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2"> Nissan Mexico </td>
        <td rowspan="2" ></td>
        <td rowspan="2" ></td>
        <td rowspan="2" ></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
         <a href="/TimsaLzc/web/app_dev.php/main/fleteDetalle/101" >
            <button class="btn btn-success">Detalles</button>
        </a> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr /> <!--magic goes here-->
    </tbody>   
</table>
```

It worked for me :)